# How to get the argmax of last 2 axes?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, numpy-ndarray, argmax

Let's say I have an array which it's dimensions are `10 X 20 X 12 X 12 X 2 X 2`. What should I do if I want to get the maximum values indices of the last two axes? meaning I want a function which will output (if the described array is the input) an array of shape: `10 X 20 X 12 X 12`. So (array is the described array):

`array[indices] == np.amax(array, (-2,-1))`

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to call the function twice, once for each axis:

```
A = np.arange(1000).reshape((10,10,10))
np.amax(np.amax(A, axis=-1), axis=-1)
```

For `np.argmax` you can basically do the same. But of course the indices are  changing. You need to correct for this.